# Redirect URL Problem Using oauth2_client Package Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-api, calendar, oauth2client

I want to get the access token and refresh token using Google OAuth2.
I was unable to pass redirect url to the android app. So, I have tried using web app.

This is My Code so far. I am unable to Figure out what must be customUriScheme and redirectUri. In Azure, I have accessed the refresh token and access token using redirect uri as com.example.calendar://oauth2redirect.
But Google doesn't allow me to add this to their redirect URL in the [webclient](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/12859863108-ipjr7migg8pip2gvobjre5po5lc1cm9c.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=calender-d3963).
But the problem is for google webclient https valid redirect scheme is required.

```
//Instantiate an OAuth2Client...
  GoogleOAuth2Client client = GoogleOAuth2Client(
    customUriScheme: 'my.test.app',
    redirectUri: 'https://my.test.app/oauth2redirect',
  );

  var token = await client.getTokenWithAuthCodeFlow(
    clientId: '',
    clientSecret: '',

    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
    ],
    authCodeParams: {"prompt": "consent", "access_type": "offline"},
  );
```

In Android Manifest
I have used this scheme in Azure to get access and refresh tokens to fetch Outlook calendar events.
I have tried the same for Google OAuth, but not worked.

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth_2.CallbackActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.example.calendar" /> 
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

// I have also tried this too...

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth_2.CallbackActivity">
    <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth_2" android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="my.test.app"
                android:pathPrefix="/oauth2redirect" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

All the Authentication and permission grants been done after that. This Site can't be reached page is shown. And the tokens are null.

[After Authentication Image from WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czy0U.jpg)

Thank You for Help.

Comment: if its an android app you need to make a mobile client not a web client. web clients are for web applications hosted on webservers  https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/google-apis

Answer (score 0):

I Have Solved this by Directly using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) Package. I have used the client ID and client secret from the Google developer console by registering a Web App. And When the Redirect occurs in the webview I queried the access token and other info.
You can refer to [Google OAuth 2.0 Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code)